# How can I get the data from a div tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the data-events value using jQuery and then change the background color of the div. This is my current situation:

```
<div class="fc-content" title="" data-events="Work In Progress"></div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("div[data-events='Work In Progress']").next().css('background-color:','#000000;'); 
});
```

The purpose is because I want to filter certain events that have a value of 'Work In Progress' and change background-color to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the div by doing the following:

```
var eventInProgress = $("div[data-events='Work In Progress']");
eventInProgress.css("background-color", "#000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Change your code to

```
$("div[data-events='Work In Progress']" ).css('background-color', 'black');
```